# How to prevent stack overflow in this recursive path finding algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, stack-overflow, path-finding

I have a function that takes two sets of numbers

```
([2,2],[6,6]) or ([4,6],[6,12]) etc.
```

Which represent indexes of elements on a 2D array.
The function takes the first set, and adds 2 randomly to either of the numbers in the array, until it both numbers are equal to the second set.
which results in a "pathAB", we go from first set to the second and push all the elements into an array.

Then i need to take the second set, and randomly subtract or add 2 to either of the numbers, until they are equal to the first set. I need to find a way back to the starting point [2,2]. The conditions are is that i can't use any of the numbers that are already used in the 'PathAB', or repeat any numbers that where already used while forming the second path. I need to avoid the first path, and "go around it".

So for input

```
([2,2], [6,6])
```

the output would be

```
  /// First Output
   
  [2, 2], // Point A
  [4, 2],
  [4, 4],
  [6, 4],
  [6, 6], /// Point B
  [4, 6],
  [2, 6],
  [2, 4],
  [2, 2], /// Point A
```

or it could be

```
  /// Second Output 
 
  [2, 2], /// Point A
  [2, 4],
  [4, 4],
  [4, 6],
  [6, 6], /// Point B
  [8, 6],
  [8, 4],
  [6, 4],
  [6, 2],
  [4, 2],
  [2, 2], /// Point A
```

The whole point is that it should be a Random Path.

I use this function to build random shapes on a two 2D array. To better understand what i'm trying to do, please have a look at the images linked below.

[First Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXYVb.png), [Second Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8xi8.png)

The red line is path A to B, or [2,2] to [6,6]. And the green line is path B to A, or [6,6] to [2,2].

The function i have right now, is able to build a path, 85% of the time
The other 15% of the time, it gives me a stack overflow error. And the wider the distance between points, the higher the chance of stack overflow. The current function only works well for very small distances.

Now to the function itself.

The making of path from A to B, is fairly simple.

```
  let pathAB = [];
  let startP;

  function makePathAB(a, b, start) {
    if (start) { /// if it's the fist iteration. add the starting point to the PathAB
      pathAB.push(a);
      startP = a;
    }
    if (a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === b[1]) return; /// A === B, path compelete
    if (a[0] > b[0] || a[1] > b[1]) {
      /// A is beyound boundaries of B, start again
      pathAB = [];
      makePathAB(startP, b, true);
    } else {
      let newA = [...a]; // Take a random index 
      let randomElem = randomInt(0, 1);
      newA[randomElem] += 2; /// go down (+2) in a random direction
      pathAB.push(newA);
      makePathAB(newA, b, false); // start next step
    }
  }
```

I take the starting point, add 2 to to either of the indexes, and then recuresively call the function until A is equal to B. If a0 or a1 is more than b0 b1 then i scrap the whole path and start again.

Then i make an array of strings from pathAB, to compare against the steps of the pathBA

```
  let compareAB = pathAB.slice(1, pathAB.length - 1).map((item) => item.toString());
```

Then for the B to A path i use this function

```
  function makePathBA(b, a, start) {
    if (start) {
      /// if starting, push first step of the path to path arr
      pathBA.push(b);
    }

    if (a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === b[1]) return; /// B === A, path, compareABelete

    if (b[0] < 0 || b[1] < 0 || b[0] > 8 || b[1] > 8) {
      /// B is out of boundaries of either A, or the array itself
      pathBA = [];
      makePathBA(startPB, a, true);
    } else {
      let newB = [...b];
      let randomElem = randomInt(0, 1);
      let plusminus = [2, -2];
      newB[randomElem] = newB[randomElem] + plusminus[randomInt(0, plusminus.length - 1)]; /// randomly go either up(-2) or down(+2)

      let crossed;

      pathBA.forEach((item) => {
        /// Check for path B crossing itself
        if (item.toString() === newB.toString()) {
          crossed = true;
        }
      });

      /// THE CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM
      compareAB.forEach((item) => {
        /// check for path BA crossing path AB
        if (item === newB.toString()) {
          crossed = true;
        }
      });

      if (crossed) {
        /// if path BA crossed itself or AB, start again from 0
        pathBA = [];
        makePathBA(startPB, a, true);
        return;
      } else {
        /// else take the next step
        pathBA.push(newB);
        crossed = false;

        makePathBA(newB, a, false);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

I take the starting point. Randomly either add or subtract 2 from either of the indexes, and if this step crosses either pathAB or itself, we start again from the starting point. If it doesn't  we go on to the next step.

THE PROBLEM, lies in the compareAB part of the function. If i don't include comparison against the AB, or "allow pathBA to cross PathAB", i never get a stack overflow, and the function works fine. But i need the paths not to cross.

How can this be done? How to prevent stack overflow, and possibly make this function work on much larger distances?

P.S The fact that the step between indexes is 2, and not 1, is irrelevant. I just need it to be 2, for building rectangular shapes on the provided array.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding `8` when you restart if `b[0] < 0 || b[1] < 0 || b[0] > 8 || b[1] > 8`? One example set of inputs you gave is `([4,6],[6,12])`, which should always fail since you're forbidding the return path to get past 8. Also if your input was something like `([0, 0], [8, 8])` and the first move on path AB is horizontal and the last move is also horizontal then there's no way to form the return path without crossing the original path since you're confined by 0 and 8, so you'll get a stack overflow.

Comment: @Andrew

I'm hardcoding 8 boundary to make it less confusing while i'm trying to make this whole thing work, one less variable to keep track of. If i make the function work as intended, i plan on adding a size parameter to make control the how big the array is.





I get your point about two horizontal moves, but the function fails even when it is perfectly possible to create a path back to A.

Comment: One thing you could try is rather than doing a move and then resetting if that move puts you in an invalid state, you could instead make a list of all valid moves (that is, moves that will put you in a valid state after doing them) and select a random move from that list or reset if the list is empty. That will cut down on how many recursive calls you'll make. You could also reorganize the code into loops rather than recursive calls so that you can have more resets (but you'll get an infinite loop if a certain path isn't possible).

Comment: Also even if it's possible to make the return path, since you're doing things randomly there's a non-zero chance that you won't create a valid path in a finite number of attempts.

Comment: *I need to avoid the first path, and "go around it".*: could it go *wide* around it? The examples have the return path stay close to the other path, but would a result be OK where the paths go really far away from each other, like making a 8x8 square?

Comment: @trincot. That's exactly what i'm trying to do. The resulting shape should be completely random, to the point of filling most or the whole array. The examples are just the first couple of results i got after while writing the post, ideally the 2d array would be much bigger, with wider more intricate paths.